# Ejecutar script con venv y python

Tags: python, bash, script, crontab

Quiero ejecutar un script en python cada 5 minutos con crontab, y tengo el "problema" o la complicación de que pertenece a un entorno virtual y usa python.

Si ejecuto el script directamente, me lo lanza bien, pero si por el contrario, lo meto en el crontab, da error.

He puesto en el crontab que me lo envié directamente a un archivo.log, pero no consigo obtener nada. También le he dado a los script permisos totales con 777 pero ni aún asi.

Dejo mi configuración de los archivos:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/python.sh >> /var/log/pypypypy.log 2>&1
```

Contenido de *python.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/venv/bin/activate
python3 /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/scrapper.py
```

Como digo, si lo ejecuto por separado, lo hace bien, con crontab no, ademas el archivo log me lo da vacío.

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Hola. Podrías intentar usando el binario del entorno virtual directamente? `/home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/venv/bin/python3 /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/scrapper.py`?

Comment: No, no puedo. He ejecutado el primer comando y me entra a la consola de python, pero el segundo no me funciona

Comment: No son 2 comando, es uno solo. La primera parte indica la ruta del intérprete a utilizar y la segunda la ubicación del archivo

Comment: Si, los he puesto, en el archivo python.sh. Igualmente desde fuera, lanzando esto -> "/home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/python.sh" funciona correctamente, pero de nuevo, en el crontab, no hace nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero sería interesante que vieramos los logs del servicio cron.

Para esto no me sé muchos trucos. Dicen que uno es utilizar:

```
$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

O su equivalente en otras distros como CentOS.

Pero su información me es poco clara.

Lo que yo hago para ver los errores es instalar postfix y mailutils:

```
$ sudo apt install -y postfix mailutils
```

`postfix` me parece que es un agente de transferencia de correos, y `mailutils` te permite tener un cliente de correos.

Esto lo hacemos porque `cron` suele enviar el estatus de las tareas por correo.

Una vez que tenemos ambos programas instalados, podemos correr un simple `mail`:

```
➜  ~ mail
"/var/mail/cuau": 6 messages 3 new 3 unread
 U   1 Cron Daemon        Wed Apr 20 23:57  22/976   Cron <cuau@cuau-1> touc ~/crontarch
 U   2 Cron Daemon        Wed Apr 20 23:58  21/951   Cron <cuau@cuau-1> touc ~/crontarch
 U   3 Cron Daemon        Wed Apr 20 23:59  21/951   Cron <cuau@cuau-1> touc ~/crontarch
>N   4 Cron Daemon        Thu Apr 21 00:00  19/932   Cron <cuau@cuau-1> 
?
```

Y seleccionas el numero del mail. Ya adentro del mail podrás leer los errores:

```
From: root@cuau-1.us-central1-a.c.test-training-301202.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: cuau-test@cuau-1.us-central2-a.c.test-training-301202.internal
Subject: Cron <cuau-test@cuau-1> touc ~/bad_py.py
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/cuau-test>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=cuau-test>
Message-Id: <20220421004201.27C2562648@cuau-1.us-central1-a.c.test-training-301202.internal>
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 00:42:01 +0000 (UTC)
X-IMAPbase: 1650501764 3
Status: O
X-UID: 2

/bin/sh: 1: touc: not found
```

Usualmente el punto de esos errores que tienes es que no tienes inicializado el ambiente y el PATH en tu script. Es decir, no es lo mismo que tu lo corras con tu shell y todo el ambiente preparado con las configuraciones de los archivos como ´~/.bashrc´, que el servicio de CRON sin el ambiente necesariamente preparado.

Podriamos tratar de adivinar y añadir esto a tu script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
. ~/.bashrc

. /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/venv/bin/activate
python3 /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper/scrapper.py
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al instalar postfix y mailutils, he conseguido ver que el error, estaba dentro del scrapper, y que es debido a "Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start:", pero como tal, la pregunta está respondida, puesto que el error no es del crontab. Me ha servido de utilidad tu respuesta, ten un buen día!